# How to print a series of rectangles

Tags: c++

I want to print out a series of rectangles, but the rectangles just show one by one, and nothing show up in the end. I don't know why. I just want all these rectangles show up together.

```
#include "Graph.h" // get access to our graphics library facilities
#include "Simple_window.h" 

int main()
{
  Graph_lib::Point tl{ 100, 100 }; 

  Simple_window win{ tl, 1000, 800, "Simple Window" }; 

  int x_size = 800;
  int y_size = 800;


  for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < x_size&&y < y_size; x += x_grid, y += y_grid)
  { 
    Graph_lib::Rectangle r(Graph_lib::Point(x, y), x_grid, y_grid); 
    r.set_fill_color(Graph_lib::Color::red); 
    win.attach(r); 
    win.wait_for_button(); 
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate language.  Is this C++?

Comment: yes,it is c++. I am a freshman, forgive me.

Comment: I don't know your library but could this: `win.wait_for_button();` be your issue? Try to move this line right after the `for` loop. I guess this function has a default waiting time.

Comment: Is this from Stroustrup's book?

Comment: wait for button is not the issue, I have tried it.

Comment: This is from the drill in the book c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are solving the drill for Chapter 13 of Stroustrup's Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition), in which he asks to plot a set of rectangles in a window, then your code is not reproducing your intent. You are plotting only 1 red rectangle, a number of times. You need a container, a vector for example, to store those rectangles and then use it to show them all together. The full code can be found  here  [link](https://github.com/bewuethr/stroustrup_ppp/blob/master/chapter13/chapter13_drill.cpp) (Credit: Benjamin Wuethrich, he actually solved all the exercises and drills of that book, have a look). Hopefully this will help you. Cheers!

Comment: Thans a lot ! It's helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. That github link is certainly helpful, I hope you will read and understand the code there, not copy ;)

Comment: Haha,actually,I have done this drill using a vector,which involves pointers introduced in the latter book.But I want to figure out a simple way. You know, simple is always better.

Comment: vector is actually simple. using stl is better. and you need to store the rectangles somewhere... that is what the vector is doing